# Issue with iPhone to Google Photos backup

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, photos, google

I typically backup photos from my iPhone (7+, iOS 11.0.1?) to Google Photos. Typically it goes quite well; I connect my phone to wifi, and the photos (all of them), automatically upload to Google Photos.

Recently, I also purchased a Cannon t6 camera. After taking pictures with that camera, I transfer them to my phone. I do not resize them during the transfer. They are all shot in RAW but to my knowledge are changed to JPEG during the transfer.

Here's the problem, all of my other pictures in my camera roll just show up in Google Photos as soon as I open the app. The pictures from the t6 that were not resized do not show up. A quick Google search of this revealed that it could be due to size or formatting, I checked this by emailing one of the images to myself, it was less than 1MB (367KB) and it was JPEG.

I just updated the Google Photos app today and that did not fix the issue. I am in the process of doing an update to iOS 11.0.2. I also tried turning my phone off and back on, that did not fix the issue either.

Has anyone had this happen before? If so, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to fix that is to use the web for uploading to Google Photos and not the iPhone since the iPhone needs to compress it, then Google Photos compresses it even more.

Use http://photos.google.com and make sure that you are signed in to your account. The quality of those images should also be much better as well.

Comment: So if the photos are already on the phone, how do I get them over to Google Photos since they aren't visible there?

Comment: See if you can upload them to a cloud drive like iCloud, Dropbox, Google Drive or Box so you can download them and then upload them onto Google Photos.